# geom_line for a parametric function

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is an example for visualizing Bezier curve:

```
library(ggplot2)
t = seq(0, 1, 0.001)
x0 = 4
y0 = 1
x1 = 28
y1 = 48
x2 = 50
y2 = 42
x3 = 40
y3 = 5
x = x0 * (1 - t)^3 + 3 * x1 * t * (1 - t)^2 + 3 * x2 * t^2 * (1 - t) + x3 * t^3 
y = y0 * (1 - t)^3 + 3 * y1 * t * (1 - t)^2 + 3 * y2 * t^2 * (1 - t) + y3 * t^3 
data = data.frame(x, y)
data1 = data.frame(x = c(x0, x2), xend = c(x1, x3), y = c(y0, y2), yend = c(y1, y3))
data2 = data.frame(x = c(x0, x1, x2, x3), y = c(y0, y1, y2, y3))
mplot = ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + geom_segment(data = data1, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) + geom_point(data = data2, aes(x, y))
mplot
```

Result:

[image]

The right part of the curve has been rendered as an area. I guess this is because the y-values are not unique for certain x-values. How to solve this?

Comment: It is indeed because the y-values are not unique. It's not really an area I think, but a line that keeps going up and down. An approximation might be yielded by replacing `geom_line()` by `geom_point()`

Comment: I think the inly way is to calculate the points on the curve and plot those. There are packages like `Hmisc` with `bezier` function which can calculate the xy coordinates or maybe `xspline` with `draw=FALSE` to get just the coordinates, but this is just an approximation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `geom_line()` you may use `geom_path()`:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_path() + 
    geom_segment(data = data1, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) + 
    geom_point(data = data2, aes(x, y))
```

[image: This is the output of the code using geom_path()]

... or even `geom_point()` would do the trick, but I guess you would have to play with point size to get what you want.

[image]